# Get GoogleAnalytics Instance in Application Class

Tags: android

I want Google Anlytics to catch all uncaught exception through my app like in Broadcast Receivers, Services and any library included.

I think by default EasyTrakcer catches Activity Uncaught Exception.

So, I decided to define an uncaught exception handler in my base application class and send the exception there. this is my code:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics;

public class ApplicationMain extends Application implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
{

    private GoogleAnalytics googleAnalytics;

    public ApplicationMain()
    {
        googleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this); // EXCEPTION OCCURS
        googleAnalytics.setDefaultTracker(googleAnalytics.getTracker("UA-300957-15"));
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable)
    {
        googleAnalytics.getDefaultTracker().sendException(throwable.getMessage(), throwable, true);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The problem is a null pointer exception occurs when trying to get Google Analytics instance using application context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

The context is still null in Application Constructor, It must be called in onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate ()
{
    googleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    googleAnalytics.setDefaultTracker(googleAnalytics.getTracker("UA-300957-15"));
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
}
```